# nuance : Speech Recognition ,algorithm for answering the user's queries

Tags: nuance

For voice activated apps(virtual assistants) like (aivc for android ), which uses nuance speech recognition, which API is used to to get the answer to the user's question. FOr example, if the user types "what is your name" the ap gives an answer.
Do we have a standard algorithm which understands the user's query and gets a probable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nuance has several speech recognition platforms/products, it depends on which one you use. For your situation, probably start out with Nuance Mix, it'a self-service speech recognition platform targeted for mobile developers. There's also Nina too which is a more full service offering from Nuance.